# Specifying $0^+$ as the lower bound of an integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, warning-messages

Consider the following evaluation.

```
Integrate[1/Sqrt[x], {x, 0, 1}]
(* 2 *)
```

The integral is right only if the first extreme of integration is $0^+$.

I want to compute the integral between 0 and 1. In that case, I expect an error in the result. Instead Mathematica gives me the result as I use the extremes of integration $0^+$ and 1.

How can I specify $0^+$ as the lower bound of the integral?

Comment: Why do you expect errors ? The anti-derivative `Integrate[1/Sqrt[x],x]` is well defined at `0`.

Comment: Hello @b.gatessucks, the extremes of integration must lie inside the domain of the function, not inside the domain of the anti-derivative. This is the answer of my professor.

Comment: It's called an improper integral (in the US) and is defined to mean the limit (of the proper integral) as you approach the boundary of the interval of integration from within the interval.  *Mathematica* does this automatically, silently.

Comment: The premise re "integral is only right if..." is not correct.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Michael E2 said, *Mathematica* does the following silently:

```
int = Integrate[1/Sqrt[x], x]
```

> 2 Sqrt[x]

And then:

```
Limit[int, x->1, Direction->"FromBelow"] - Limit[int, x->0, Direction->"FromAbove"]
```

> 2

Since the antiderivative `2 Sqrt[x]` is continuous, taking limits is equivalent to evaluation on the limit points. In *Mathematica*, this can be done as follows:

```
(int /. x -> 1) - (int /. x -> 0)
```

> 2

Hence, there is no need for an error message.

Comment: In general one needs `int` to be continuous on the integration domain to apply the fundamental theorem of calculus (this is the case for your answer already). The symbolic definite integral `int = Integrate[1/Sqrt[t], {t, x, 1}, Assumptions -> 0 < x < 1]` will ensure this. However compared to indefinite integration the call is, in general, slower and less reliable to return a result.

Comment: And for a good read, check out one of my favorite [Wolfram blog posts](https://blog.wolfram.com/2008/01/19/mathematica-and-the-fundamental-theorem-of-calculus/).

Comment: Hello @HenrikSchumacher, thank you so much for your extremely clear explanation.

Comment: You're welcome!